# Fully updating QGIS' GUI after changing a layer style via Python

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, symbology

Let's say I changed a layer's style via PyQGIS:

```
# load "world" easter egg layer and then:
layer = iface.activeLayer()
layer.renderer().symbol().setColor(QColor.fromRgb(50,50,250))
```

## Result

- The map display is unchanged, the map does not automatically update
- The icon in the layer tree is the same as before, also not automatically updated
- The layer styling panel still shows the previous color, also not automatically updated
- I don't know where else the old style is still referenced...

## Updating

- I can move the map or `layer.triggerRepaint()` to update the map display
- I can `iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(layer.id())` to update the symbol in the layer tree
- I can `layer.emitStyleChanged()` or open and close the layer styling panel to update that
- I don't know where else the old style is still referenced...

## Question

There must be a better way, like a single signal to emit or method to call, to shout to the world that the layer's symbology has updated and things have to update. How do I do that in a proper, fail-safe and complete way?